# Inequality on the number of paths in a graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, directed-graphs

Let $G$ be an undirected graph with $n$ nodes and let $a_k$ denote the number of directed paths of length $k$.

Prove that $$a_1 \leq \sqrt{n a_2}.$$
Note that $a \to b \to a$, where $a$ and $b$ are adjacent nodes in $G$, is considered a path of length $2$.
Also, it is easy to see that $a_1 \leq a_2.$

Let $A$ denote the adjacency matrix of $G$. I know that the sum of elements of $A$ is $a_1$
and that $a_2$ is the sum of elements of $A^2$. I tried to use that but couldn't get anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

$a_1 = \sum_{v} \deg(v)$ and $a_2 = \sum_v \deg(v)^2$, where the latter is obtained by letting $v$ be the "middle vertex" of the length-2 path we're constructing.

With that in mind, the inequality you're asking for is exactly the [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) $|\langle \mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b} \rangle | \le \|\mathbf{a}\| \|\mathbf{b}\|$ where $\mathbf{a} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is the list of vertex degrees and $\mathbf{b} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a vector of all $1$s.